# numpy: vectorized cumulative sum along two axes

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to implement the functionality of `numpy.cumsum` across two axes simultaneously in a vectorized fashion. That is, the value of any cell in the output should be the sum total of all cells above and to the left, inclusive, of the corresponding cell in the input.

This is equivalent to applying `cumsum` sequentially across first one axis, then another:

```
>>> X = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)
>>> X
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
>>> np.cumsum(np.cumsum(X, axis=0),axis=1)
array([[  0,   1,   3,   6,  10],
       [  5,  12,  21,  32,  45],
       [ 15,  33,  54,  78, 105],
       [ 30,  64, 102, 144, 190],
       [ 50, 105, 165, 230, 300]])
```

However I think this is a relatively inefficient way to do this.

Is vectorization possible in numpy/Python such that the array only needs to be summed once?

Comment: This won't be faster, but for cleaner code, you can use `np.apply_over_axes`: `np.apply_over_axes(np.cumsum, X, axes=[0,1])`

Comment: The double cumsum looks clean enough to me.

Comment: For reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed-area_table

Comment: I think the cumsum looks slightly cleaner if you use the method and not the function: `X.cumsum(0).cumsum(1)`.  And I'd be very surprised if this was a dominant factor in the time taken by any real algorithm.

Comment: `np.add.reduce` says that `axis` may be a tuple, i.e. several axes.  But `np.add.accumulate` explicitly says multiple axes is not allowed; recommending repeated use instead.  That's true of all the `ufunc`.

Comment: @hpaulj I think it may end up being the best way to go. I'm not sure if I have used `timeit` properly in evaluating the `numba` method outlined below (I know `numba` needs to compile the function before use, & I suspect what I was doing with `timeit` was resulting in re-compilation for every repetition)... however preliminary results suggest repeated use of `cumsum` may be significantly faster.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better solution, but it's possible with `numba.stencil`:

```
import numba
# Define some input array
x = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)
# Pad the array to one cell width with 0
y = np.pad(x, 1, mode='constant', constant_values=0)

# Instantiate the output array
ii = np.zeros_like(y)

@numba.stencil
def integral_image(A, B):
    # A is the input array, B is the output
    return A[0,0] + B[-1,0] + B[0,-1] - B[-1,-1]

# Slice the output to get rid of padded cells
ii = integral_image(y, ii, out=ii)[1:-1,1:-1]
```

This generates a stencil function which uses values from the input image along with previously-calculated values from the output. The output needs to be instantiated as an array of zeros before performing the calculation and must be passed to the stencil function as an output array so that the function has access to the previously-calculated values.

My primary issue with this is that it requires copying the input array to pad it for use with `numba.stencil`. It seems that the `numba` developers are thinking about adding adding different modes for boundary handling at some point, but currently it is necessary to pad the input in order for the stencil to be applied over every cell.

I am also not sure how much faster this is compared to `x.cumsum(0).cumsum(1)`. When I get around to performance-testing this against successive calls to `np.cumsum` I'll try to remember to post the specs.